# How do I tell which widget triggered an event in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have several widgets bound to the same function call. How do I tell which one triggered that call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event has a widget field that may help you to distinguish which widget is the source:

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyObj:
    def callback(self, event):
        print event.widget.message

obj = MyObj()
root = Tk()
btn=Button(root, text="Click")
btn.bind('<Button-1>', obj.callback)
btn.pack()
btn.message = 'Hello'

btn2=Button(root, text="Click too")
btn2.bind('<Button-1>', obj.callback)
btn2.message = 'Salut'
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```